# How can I check a USB fingerprint scanner device on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: drivers, usb, software-recommendation, scanner, fingerprint-reader

I just bought a USB fingerprint scanner from Idemia ([link](https://www.amazon.in/Safran-Morpho-Idemia-Fingerprint-Scanner/dp/B07W7BD9Q7)) and I want to check if it is working. **I do not want to use this for login on my Ubuntu 20.04 laptop.** I only want to check if my laptop is detecting the device correctly and whether it's able to read fingerprints.

**Are there any utilities or softwares on Ubuntu 20.04 that can do this?**

Comment: The device shows up as "Sagem CBM/MSO1300 Fingerprint Sensor" on `lsusb`.

Comment: wouldn't testing it to log in to your laptop be the best way to test if it is working?